# Libfreenect2 point cloud frame capture

Tags: linux, computer-vision, kinect

I've been looking through the Libfreenect2 repo if there is the possibility to capture just 1 point cloud frame out of my Kinect V2, by using Ubuntu 16.04lt, but I cannot find anything relevant to do so.

How would that possible?

Answer (score 1):

[libfreenect](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect) and [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2) are mostly just drivers for Kinect devices.  Post-processing is best applied in a middleware layer such as [pointclouds.org](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php) or [AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/ec99e402-afc6-f187-4269-8e640ef5a26f.htm); it depends on the goals of your application.

If you really want to get your hands dirty, check out this [C++ point cloud](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/wrappers/cpp/cpp_pc_view.cpp) example.  It's written for the Kinect v1, but it might give you some ideas.  If you have trouble getting the hardware to work, please also visit the repositories linked above for documentation and bug reports.